# what is the point of making directories in a cisco cli

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios, cli

what is the point of making directories in a Cisco router.
I noticed its was kinda like Linux mkdir and all that stuff, but what is the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cisco devices have a filesystem, much like other computing devices. I really don't understand your confusion. The file system is used to store boot images an other necessary files.

> I noticed its was kinda like Linux mkdir and all that stuff

Did you ever think that Linux was like Cisco IOS, which predates Linux by many years?

Comment: so, they are there for storing files and other stuff ?

Comment: Yes. You can have multiple instances of IOS images, there are things like the HTTP pages, etc. Cisco has always had a filesystem for its files.

Comment: Just a comment on chronology: Linux (first released 1991), is of course developed to be like Unix, which had `mkdir` and `chdir` in its first release in 1972. Unix copied the hierarchical filesystem (and many other innovations) from Multics (1969) which had "create directory" as `cd` and "change working directory" was `cwd`.  Cisco was founded in 1984.

Comment: @jonathanjo, I was just being kind of a smartass. I knew the chronology. We once had a person assert that IOS was derived from Linux, but Ricky set him straight.

Comment: @RonMaupin I was just being kind of a historian -- seemed like a good idea to have the dates on this answer for any who didn't know the chronology.  Kind regards.

Comment: @jonathanjo, it was just a few years after Unix was released (1978-79) that I took a class in C and Unix programming in college. The college had to get a new computer to be able to offer the class because Unix was owned by the old AT&T at that time.